# String replacement with Perl without assigning a variable

Tags: perl

I am aware that strings in Perl are not immutable so the natural string substitution method is `$var =~ s/re/$with/g`.

However this is extremely limiting to me as a programmer used to things such as

JS:

```
string.replace(/re/g, with)
```

Bash:

```
${var//re/$with}
```

The only workaround I see is to declare a subroutine which performs this task, and it's straightforward to implement this but it would need to be duplicated or imported everywhere in my code that does this. Is this the only way?

Comment: Could you make it clearer what you are trying to do? I can’t quite see your problem between all the trolling. Oh, and what perl version are you using? Is it ≥ v5.14 ?

Comment: I guess it could be fair to call that trolling. I was working on something that wasn't pretty at the time. The quick answers are appreciated, however.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `r` modifier for `s///`. It will perform a non-destructive substitution (leaving the left operand unmodified) and return the result of the substitution. You'll need Perl 5.13.2 or later.

```
say $var =~ s/re/$with/gr; # print result of replacing "re" with $with in $var
say $var; # print original $var, without anything substituted
```

Comment: here's an example:  `print "hello" =~ s/e/b/r;` returns `hbllo`

Comment: Oh that's great, we're not even on 5.14 over here. But just to be clear on how to use this: `expr_producing_string() =~ s/re/$with/gr` evaluates to the replaced string?

Comment: @StevenLu Yes. On older Perls you'll have to work around it like `do {(my $temp = $var) =~ s///; $temp}`.